# SQL Server 2014 Installs to windows partition, not D drive

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014

Installing SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012 R2 (VM).  In the Feature Selection page, I can change the `Instance Root Directory`, the `Shared Feature Directory`, and the `Shared Feature Directory (x86)`.

I've set all to install to `D:\Program files`, but as I start checking features, the disk space usage on the primary OS partition grows.  With all Instance features selected, I'm using 2.2 GB on the D drive, and 676 MB on the C drive... eh, fine, I'll live.

As I start to check Shared Features, the drive usage on C grows faster than on D.  Adding the Reporting Services for SharePoint, for example, bumps the C drive usage to 1.75 GB (the D drive usage remains the same).  By the time I'm done picking all the features I want, I have 3.2 GB on the C drive, and 2.8 GB on the D drive!!

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened but i guess you can resolve with below solution.
1- install vm to D:drive 
2- install sqlserver  on vm disk. (D drive)
3- After the install. Stop sqlserver and deteach database 
4- Move database files (.mdf and .ldf) to shared folder
5- Attach database again

Comment: It isn't just data files that are a problem - they're fully on the D:\ partition.  It's that the installation puts SQL Server application components on both drives.